# How to reach a function from a directive that is defined in the inline controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

If I have a `directive`, that has its own `controller` defined in its body:

```
directives.directive("formWrapper", ['User','$location',  function(User, $location) {

    return {
       ...
       template: '<div>' +
                   '<input ng-click="cancel()" type="button" value="Cancel"/>' +
                   '<input ng-click="save()" type="button" value="Save" />' +
                  '</div>',

       controller: function($scope, $location, User) {

            $scope.fields = User.get( {username: "username"}  );

            var save = function() {...}

            var cancel = function() {...}          
        }
    }
}]);
```

In a `template` section I'm trying to reach functions `save()` and `cancel()` which are defined in the controller.

For now it does not work clicking on those buttons nothing happens.

> I really don't want to define `save()` and `cancel()` in the `$scope`,
>   because only this directive is supposed to use them. Or maybe it
>   is ok to make them being in the `$scope`? Not sure about that
>   isolation.

**Q:** How can I achieve it? Some common solution / vision about that?

Comment: Hoping it is not rhetorical question.

Comment: its absolutely fine to put the functions in scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put `save()` and `cancel()` on the directive's scope so the template can see them (right now they're only visible inside the controller function).

So instead of:

```
var save = function() {...}
var cancel = function() {...}
```

You want

```
$scope.save = function() {...}
$scope.cancel = function() {...}
```

It's fine for these to be on the directive scope.  It's not like putting them on `$rootScope` which is global.

You'll notice I added this to your directive:

```
scope: {},
```

That makes this `$scope` restricted to just this directive (AKA "isolated scope").  So you can think of this like an object or function scope- you're not polluting global namespace.

Here's a demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/uLfLM/1/